# Alternative for using constructor in traits

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I have a trait, solely responsible for Hashing ID.

```
trait Hasher
{
    protected $hasher;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $salt = $this->hashSalt ?? null;
        $length = $this->hashLength ?? null;
        $chars = $this->hashChars ?? null;

        $this->hasher = new Hashids($salt, $length, $chars);

        parent::__construct(); // I hoped this would trigger MyModel's constructor 
                               // but it doesn't work as expected.
     }
}
```

I tried using it in my model.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    use Hasher;

    private $hashSalt = 'Test';
    private $hashChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    private $hashLength = 6;
}
```

The idea was making this reusable and I didn't want to write all this Hasher logic into my model.

The issue with `parent::__construct();` in constructor causes `MyModel`'s constructor not to trigger and `Model`'s constuctor trying fetching data from `Hasher` (as I understand).

I know I can create a new class that extends Model and use `MyModel extends BaseModel`, but I'm not a huge fan of extending Model class. (Hopefully this is not the only way)

What other ideas do you have for solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Eloquent bootstrappers/initializers.

```php
trait Hasher
{
    protected $hasher;

    protected function initializeHasher()
    {
        $salt = $this->hashSalt ?? null;
        $length = $this->hashLength ?? null;
        $chars = $this->hashChars ?? null;

        $this->hasher = new Hashids($salt, $length, $chars);
     }
}
```

By implementing a method in your trait named `initialize{traitName}`, Laravel will automatically call it in constructor. The same thing happens if you implement a static method named `boot{traitName}`, it will be called on the first time you use your model. Here is a full explanation

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct`

```php
/**
     * Create a new Eloquent model instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->bootIfNotBooted();

        $this->initializeTraits();

        $this->syncOriginal();

        $this->fill($attributes);
    }
```

Two things are important here, the `bootIfNotBooted` call indirectly triggers this method

```php
/**
     * Boot all of the bootable traits on the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function bootTraits()
    {
        $class = static::class;

        $booted = [];

        static::$traitInitializers[$class] = [];

        foreach (class_uses_recursive($class) as $trait) {
            $method = 'boot'.class_basename($trait);

            if (method_exists($class, $method) && ! in_array($method, $booted)) {
                forward_static_call([$class, $method]);

                $booted[] = $method;
            }

            if (method_exists($class, $method = 'initialize'.class_basename($trait))) {
                static::$traitInitializers[$class][] = $method;

                static::$traitInitializers[$class] = array_unique(
                    static::$traitInitializers[$class]
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

You can notice here the logic I explained earlier, the bootstrappers are called and the initializers are registered (but not called yet).
Then the constructor calls this

```php
/**
     * Initialize any initializable traits on the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initializeTraits()
    {
        foreach (static::$traitInitializers[static::class] as $method) {
            $this->{$method}();
        }
    }
```

And this way, each initializer previously registered gets called.

Comment: Oh, that's great info here. Didn't realize `initializeTraits()`. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you declare a function in the trait and call it in your Model's constructor like so:

```
trait Hasher
{
    protected $hasher;

    public function hash()
    {
        $salt = $this->hashSalt ?? null;
        $length = $this->hashLength ?? null;
        $chars = $this->hashChars ?? null;

        $this->hasher = new Hashids($salt, $length, $chars);
     }
}
```

And then in your model's constructor:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    use Hasher;

    private $hashSalt = 'Test';
    private $hashChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    private $hashLength = 6;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hash();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even though it also works, Shizzen83's answer is more of a Laravel way to do.

Comment: I agree, it reduces the effort. Thanks for checking out my answer though